# Magento 2 Stripe module changes price of product over custom price

Tags: magento2, product, guest-checkout

I'm trying to add to cart a product with custom and base price. It's working file.

The problem is that Stripe checkout module has an **update** button that adds the address of a guest customer to billing address, and when that happens my product's price get backs to original.

Here is my controller where I set the custom price.

```
public function execute(){
        $request = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        $product_id = $request['product_id'];
        $price = $request['grand_total'];
        $params = array(
            'formKey' => $this->formKey,
            'product_id' => $product_id,
            'qty' => 1
        );

        $productFactory = $this->product->create();
        try{
            $product = $productFactory->load($product_id);
           
            $product->setPrice($price);
            $product->setBasePrice($price);
            $product->setIsSuperMode(true);
            $this->cart->addProduct($product,$params);
            $this->cart->save();
        }
        catch(\Exception $e){
            return $request;
        }
    }
```

Is there any solution for this that does not involves modifying Stripe's module ?

Maybe changing product's price from database dinamically?

Thanks and greetings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1: Create Events/xml File**

Firstly, you need to create events/xml in the folder Vendor/Module/etc/frontend and use event checkout_cart_product_add_after

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="customprice" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CustomPrice" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**Step 2: Create CustomPrice.php File**

Now, you have to create CustomPrice.php file that override your price in the Observer Folder.

```
<?php
    /**
     * Vendor Module CustomPrice Observer
     *
     * @category    Vendor
     * @package     Vendor_Module
     * @author      Vendor Module
     *
     */
    namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;
 
    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
 
    class CustomPrice implements ObserverInterface
    {
        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
            $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');         
            $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
            $price = 100; //set your price here
            $item->setCustomPrice($price);
            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
            $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
        }
 
    }
```

I think after that your stripe module will not change price.
Note: According to your need for setting a custom price for one or more products, you can manipulate this by adding conditions.

accept solution if works for you.

Comment: Hi, it worked, but do you know how can I send $price value to the Observer? I don't know how to send paremeters to observer. Greetings!

Comment: You can create a session variable and unset it once price set successfully..